# Dropzone unable to upload and move files into folder

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, dropzone.js

Hi I'm new to jquery and dropzone library,
I unable to upload files using dropzone. I wanted to do multiple file upload using dropzone whenever I drag and drop multiple image or doc inside dropzone and click submit, I have edit and change all my code and it still not working.. I unable to move or upload the files into the folder.
Any help and suggestion please. I use here as reference https://github.com/enyo/dropzone/wiki/Combine-normal-form-with-Dropzone.

**Javascript**

```
var unique = 'ufiles';
Dropzone.options.myAwesomeDropzone = {
    url: "../../scripts/submission-upload.php",
    autoProcessQueue: false,
    autoDiscover: false,
    uploadMultiple: true,
    parallelUploads: 100,
    paramName: unique,
    previewsContainer: ".dropzone-previews",
    maxFilesize: 50, //MB
    maxFiles: 100,
    acceptedFiles: "image/*, application/pdf, .doc, .docx",
    addRemoveLinks: true,
    dictRemoveFile: 'Remove',
    dictFileTooBig: 'File is bigger than 50MB',
    accept: function(file, done) {
        console.log("uploaded");
        done();
    },
    error: function(file, msg){
        alert(msg);
    },
    init: function () {
        var myDropzone = this;

        // First change the button to actually tell Dropzone to process the queue.

        $('input[type=submit]').on("click", function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            e.stopPropagation();
            myDropzone.processQueue();
            //$("#upload-forms").submit();
        });
        // Listen to the sendingmultiple event. In this case, it's the sendingmultiple event instead
        // of the sending event because uploadMultiple is set to true.
        this.on("sendingmultiple", function() {
            // Gets triggered when the form is actually being sent.
            // Hide the success button or the complete form.
            $("#upload-forms").submit();
        });
        this.on("successmultiple", function(files, response) {
            // Gets triggered when the files have successfully been sent.
            // Redirect user or notify of success.
        });
        this.on("errormultiple", function(files, response) {
            // Gets triggered when there was an error sending the files.
            // Maybe show form again, and notify user of error
        });
    }
}
```

**Upload PHP**

```
$uploaddir = '../submissions/';
$uploadfile = $uploaddir.$_FILES['ufiles']['name'];
foreach ($FILE['ufiles']['tmp_name'] as $file) {
  echo $file;
  if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['ufiles']['tmp_name'], $uploadfile)) {
    echo "File is valid, and was successfully uploaded.\n";
  } else {
    echo "Error!\n";
  }
}
```

**HTML**

```
<form method="post" action="scripts/submission-upload.php" id="upload-forms" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <div class="dropzone dropzone-previews" id="my-awesome-dropzone">
    <div class="fallback">
      <input name="file[]" type="file" multiple>
    </div>
  </div>
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Do you get any errors in console?

Comment: no, it's just unable to find the id="uploadedfiles" even I try to echo $uploadfile; comes out nothing..

Comment: Try `echo $_FILES['file']['name']`

Answer (score 0):

The submit button inside form tag trigger two events i.e, its default form submission and your function. You need to perform you function before default form submission.
Instead of doing this

```
$('#submit').submit(function(){
     dropzone.processQueue();
});
```

Do this

```
<form onsubmit="return someFunction();" ...>
```

And write a function like this

```
function someFunction(){
    dropzone.processQueue();
    return false;
}
```

I found a similar solution here also [Javascript shortcuts for loops, conditions and return functions](http://javascriptsolution.com/javascript-shortcuts-for-loops-conditions-and-return-functions/)

Comment: Thanks for reply, I have try the method it doesn't work.. I try echo out $_FILES['file']['name']; it came out nothing..

Answer (score 0):

Dropzone `name` parameter is set to `file` as default. If you would like to change that, you can change it with [paramName](http://www.dropzonejs.com/#config-paramName).

So, in your PHP you would try to get the file array by using `$_FILES['file']` and not by the id.

Since you will be uploading multiple files and `uploadMultiple` is set to `true`, you would need to loop through the `$_FILES['file']` array. Take a look at this:

```
$uploaddir = '../submissions/';

foreach($_FILES['file'] as $file){
    $uploadfile = $uploaddir.$file['name'];
    // Move file here etc...
}
```

Comment: I have try echo $_FILES['file']['name'] its came out nothing too :(